# UIImagePickerController how to hide the flip camera button?

Tags: objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

is there a way to hide the flip camera button inside the UIImagePickerController?

thanks for reading 
!^_^!

Comment: Yes, `[picker setShowsCameraControls:FALSE];` but then you have to add your custom controls.

Comment: thanks for responding, already tried this way, although it would be very nice if i can hide just the flip button. nevertheless, i think might have to add my custom controls. thanks

Answer (score 6):

I ended up using a custom subclass of UIImagePickerController to fix this (and other) issues:

```
#import "SMImagePickerController.h"

@implementation SMImagePickerController

void hideFlipButtonInSubviews(UIView *view) {
    if ([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"CAMFlipButton"]) {
        [view setHidden:YES];
    } else {
        for (UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
             hideFlipButtonInSubviews(subview);
        }    
    }    
}    

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    hideFlipButtonInSubviews(self.view);
}    

@end
```

Comment: The view is named CMKFlipButton in newer iOS versions

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to create an empty button inside an overlayview that you float on top of the flip camera button.   I hacked the code below to test and it seemed to work.   Give it a try.

```
UIView *cameraOverlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenSize.width - 100.0f, 5.0f, 100.0f, 35.0f)];
[cameraOverlayView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
UIButton *emptyBlackButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 35.0f)];
[emptyBlackButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[emptyBlackButton setEnabled:YES];
[cameraOverlayView addSubview:emptyBlackButton];

cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
cameraUI.showsCameraControls = YES;
cameraUI.delegate = self;

cameraUI.cameraOverlayView = cameraOverlayView;
```

Comment: This works great...until I realized that the view is completely visible in video mode.  But still, appreciated.

Comment: Works in landscape on iPad, but needs more work if you want to deal with screen rotation.