# How to hide Front Camera in UIImage Picker?

Tags: ios

I am using UIimage picker i have to hide front Camera Option from my code, but front camera not removing

here is my code line

```
        if( [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront] || [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear])
        {
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        }


       [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this answer: [How to hide flip camera button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525736/uiimagepickercontroller-how-to-hide-the-flip-camera-button).
I guess you'll need to set `showsCameraControls` to `NO` and create your own model in top of UIImagePickerView.