# How to disable rear/front camera switching option in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am building an app to capture image(video) using **UIImagePickerController**. As my requirement is concerned I want to disable only the **Rear/Front camera switching control**. I tried the following code,

```
showsCameraControls=NO;
```

But it cancels **all** the controls like focus, flash. Can anyone suggest any solutions to disable rear/front switching control in **UIImagePicker**?

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525736/uiimagepickercontroller-how-to-hide-the-flip-camera-button

Comment: I tried that solution. It uses overlay view, which just hides controls.

Comment: Hi, check my answer. You can use NBUCamera, a third party tool for this

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

1. You can hide the flip camera button by adding an overlay(UIView) on top of the button.
2. You can use a third party library for camera like [NBUCamera](https://github.com/CyberAgent/iOS-NBUImagePicker) where you can switch toggle camera control

Feel free to suggest edits to make this better

Answer (score 0):

If you want the users to use the front camera. You can set `cameraDevice` to `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront`. If you want to hide it, you must customize the overlay view by yourself.

Comment: Is there any other solution? Because overlay view hides all controls and it doesn't work fine in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can not hide only camera filp button in **UIImagePickerController** but you can use below library for customize camera controll

https://github.com/omergul123/LLSimpleCamera