# How to disable the camera switch button in iphone

Tags: ios, camera, front-camera

I am doing one application. In that I am using the camera to take the pictures from rear camera only. So I want to disable the camera switch button(rear to front and front to rear). So please guide me how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIImagePickerController how to hide the flip camera button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525736/uiimagepickercontroller-how-to-hide-the-flip-camera-button)

Answer (score 1):

In objective-c

```
picker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
```

In swift (I used 2.3)

```
picker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Rear
imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,screenSize.width,40))
        imagePicker.cameraOverlayView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Comment: If i turn to landscape mode,on that time again flip button is appearing,And my app supports portrait only

Comment: This link might help with camera orientations
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14812010/5409618

If you can know that the orientation is landscape, you can change the code as:

imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(screenSize.width - 40,0,40,screenSize.height))